# Magento 2 - Product title h1

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, products, product-view

How can i add a custom attribute to the product view h1 title?

I have created a new module with your files and this files:

> /app/code/ELLA/Producttitle/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="producttitle" frontName="producttitle">
        <module name="ELLA_Producttitle" />
    </route>
</router>
```

> /app/code/ELLA/Producttitle/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="ELLA_Producttitle" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

> /app/code/ELLA/Producttitle/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'ELLA_Producttitle',
__DIR__ );
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
<action method="setPageTitle">
    <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data::getTitle"></argument>
</action>
```

> /app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        $title = $this->product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Nothing would happen. You have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to SE ! you should be more specific about your question, please add more details, what you have tried? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried to find the h1 tag like in m1, but in m2 i only find that the page title would set in the view.php. There i don't want to manipulate the file. I want to achieve that the manufacturer would be added to the h1 tag in the product detail page.

Comment: For the future...if you have additional info about your question, edit the question. Don't post answers that are not answers. This is not a forum.

Comment: ok Marius sorry im new here.. i will respect this for future. So if i have changed something in code so i should edit my post and not write a answer?

Comment: Right. Answers should be used for possible solutions only. If you haved changed something or have additional information add it to your question. If you found a solution at your own, you can also answer your own question and mark your answer as acceped (if there is no better one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change title from xml, as you want to set Manufacturer as title, you can set title using helper (for this you have to create a custom module or can add code in existing module).

First you have to add below code at

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data::getTitle"></argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then code in your helper file at below path

> /app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $registry;

        public function __construct
        (
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
        ) {
            $this->registry = $registry;
        }

        public function getTitle()
        {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
            $title = $this->product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
            return $title;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have packed it in a new module, but doesn't work. See code of module in question. I compared it with your tutorial too.

Comment: @ThomasS. try one more thing, if your module is enable then add the xml code to `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file

Comment: doesn't work sry. I had tested now the module with Hello World Output like in the tutorial. That works. So the error is not in the module.

Comment: I have tested this before posting as answer and it was working on my side, try checking if you helper function is working or not, Also make sure you have gave proper name to file and are on proper path

Comment: I'm so sorry! Now it works after put xml code in app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml ! Thank you for your help!